# Need Help got NULL value when Typecast while Passing object of a class as parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I am passing an object as a parameter. When I retrieve the data by the passed object parameter by Typecast then I am getting NULL value. Its strange to view the sample data when I do mouse-over on passing parameter like data and by Null value when assigning by casting .

The NULL value are the below statement :

```
FirmwareUpdatePackage firmwareUpdatePackage = data as FirmwareUpdatePackage;
```

Code:

```
public static class CommandsHandler
{
     private static void GetCommand(Command command, object data)
     {
         switch (command)
         {
            case Command.UpdateFW:
                FirmwareUpdatePackage firmwareUpdatePackage = data as FirmwareUpdatePackage; 
                // processing..
                break;
          }
     }
}
```

My problem is that `data` is not casting to `FirmwareUpdatePackage`

Supporting and Calling sample class and function :

```
Private void mainFunctin()
{   
    var pkgData= CreateEmptyPackageData();
    var packageData = new FirmwareUpdatePackage { Address = 121, Data = pkgData};

    // Command is an ENUM.

     CommandsHandler.GetCommand(Command.FirmwareUpdateData, packageData);
}
```

Populated the Package:

```
private static byte[] CreateEmptyPackageData()
{
     var data = new byte[256];
     for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
          data[i] = 255;
}
```

Passed Data Screen Shot as requested : 
[image]

[image]
Sample Screen shot of data by mouse hover :

[image]

Null Value : 
[image]

[image]

Null Value screen shot
[image]

Comment: Does this even compile?
At first packageData is of type byte[] (the return type of CreateEmptyPackageData), and then it's assigned an object of type FirmwareUpdatePackage.

Comment: `packageData` is defined twice and won't compile. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is sample code I have just edit the part of code is fully compile and I have attached the screen shot of the passing data.

Comment: _"I have attached the screen shot of the passing data."_ - and that screenshot shows it's a byte array.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the value of data, before casting.

Comment: Your posted code and your screenshotted code are different, and they keep changing, making this question hard to answer. It's like you're deliberately obfuscating/simplifying your code, but breaking it at the same time.. When you've finished editing your question let us know..

Comment: Also, show your `using` block; i feel theres a risk that there are duplicate classnames in different namespaces. Lastly, after you did your cast, also type `?data.GetType()` into the immediate window and post the result

Comment: I have added more screen shot of Live Data

Comment: Is it the same FirmwareUpdatePackage type? Meaning, did you get it from the same assembly, same version, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Use a cast instead of `as`:

```
var firmwareUpdatePackage = (FirmwareUpdatePackage)data;
```

That way you'll get a helpful error message if the cast cannot be made:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Some.Other.Namespace.FirmwareUpdatePackage' to type 'Circassia.Core.Engine.FirmwareUpdatePackage'

Comment: Passing Object data is actully the  class object with  int Address and  byte[] Data. And I can see the sample data when I execute it.